# How to install NodeJS LTS on Windows as a local user (without admin rights)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm using Windows as a simple user (I don't have any admin rights) and want to install NodeJS LTS.

On the [download site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) I have the choice to download only the binary `node.exe` (which don't includes `npm`) or the `node.msi` installer which requires the admin rights to execute.

How can I manually install `node.exe` and also be able to use `npm`?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

#### UPDATE 10/2018

On Node's download page referenced in step 1. there is now a **.zip archive download** which contains both the **nodejs executable and npm**. Unpacking that to a suitable path and adding this path to your PATH environment variable (step 2.) will give you both node and npm (so you can skip steps 3. - 6.).

Let say you want to install it into `%userprofile%\Applications\nodejs-lts`, let's name it `<NODE_PATH>`.

1. [Download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) the LTS `node.exe` binary for Windows and copy it to `<NODE_PATH>`.
2. Add `<NODE_PATH>` to your `PATH` environment variable (`set PATH=<NODE_PATH>;%PATH%` or using [Windows user interface](https://superuser.com/q/25037/136024))
3. Download the stable at `https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-{VERSION}.tgz` npm package (following [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node))
4. Unzip the `npm-{VERSION}.tgz` anywhere (using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for example)
5. Launch a `cmd` and `cd` into the place where you have unzipped npm
6. Execute: `node cli.js install -gf` or `node bin/npm-cli.js install npm -gf` on certain versions (thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029089/how-to-install-nodejs-lts-on-windows-as-a-local-user-without-admin-rights/37029090?noredirect=1#comment76298984_37029090))

The last command is specified in the `Makefile` for target `install`, target which the `README.md` invites to execute when manually installing.

Comment: @Anthony What does step 6 do here?  Thanks.

Comment: @KiranPagar it is the command specified in the `Makefile` for target `install`, target which the `README.md` invites to execute when manually installing.

Comment: I wonder how i'm supposed to add it to the PATH var if can't update it as i don't have admin rights !

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah yes you can, in your **user**'s `PATH` environment variable: http://superuser.com/a/133459/136024

Comment: I don't have such a variable on my user variable panel. Am i supposed to create a "PATH" variable with the same name as the "PATH" variable for the system ( which i can't modify)

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah yes exactly. The values will be merged for your user.

Comment: For me it was this the commant i had to use: `node bin/npm-cli.js install npm -gf`

Comment: Thank you @xavipen, that worked for me, with only one thing more... in case someone else did not figure out...   at first the error: `npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\...\node-v6\npm.cmd: is outside C:\Users\...\node-v6\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\...\node-v6\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.`   Just do what it says...  at the node directory, move the npm files (cmd / sh) from there and run again the command.

Comment: btw. in some environment with strong acl, the logged in user has no execution right to set the path variable. then the installation will then fail

Comment: @MattOpen you mean, even in his/her own **user**'s `PATH`? I don't think there is such ACL, is there?

Comment: @AnthonyO. If your PC is part of a domain then a system admin can define the ACL . more about this https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @MattOpen yes I know that but he can't forbid you to set your own **user**'s `PATH` (I'm not talking about the system's `PATH`, but the user's one) can he?

Comment: @AnthonyO.can`t answer finally, but actually sitting at my client with strong acl and I was able to set user var only for the current cmd window. After closing this cmd window, my env variable were reset to default - I am not able to set user var permanently. cheers

Comment: @MattOpen you just have to open the "windows menu", right-click on "Computer" > properties the click on the "advanced settings" button, then on "Environment variables" then you should be able to modify / add environment variables in the top list "user variables for <your username>".

Comment: @AnthonyO.as I said before, "STRONG ACL" there is no menu at present, it is denied by admin rules.

Comment: Windows Defender Firewall on my computer prevents node from downloading dependencies from the npm registry. Can that be fixed somehow? (I do not have admin rights)

Comment: ´set PATH=<NODE_PATH>;%PATH%´ prepends path to the system path. But after restart it disappears. I there a way to keep it permanently without admin rights?

Comment: @o-sapov I think you will find the answer to this question [here](https://serverfault.com/a/548112/93281)

Comment: When executing ```node bin/npm-cli.js install npm -gf``` im receiving the error:

npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: @RuudvandeVen `request to registry.npmjs.org/npm failed` : it seems that you have some enterprise proxy or something that forbids downloading from registry.npmjs.org ?

Comment: Thanks without this I couldn't have learnt about web development in my office laptop

Comment: What if your administrator has disabled the command prompt (cmd)?

Answer (score 57):

The nodejs version of 6.11 LTS and later seems to be easier to install, because npm is already included.

1. Download the [node.js LTS binary for Windows](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and extract it to your
   desired location
2. Add the path of the nodejs folder to the PATH environment variable: 
   (Shortcut winkey+R and enter: `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`)
3. Open a new command window (winkey+R and type `cmd`)
4. Type `node -v` and `npm -v` to verify the installation

Comment: Worked like a charm as of today with 8.9.4. Thanks!
I would suggest to edit the point 3: "Open a new command window (CMD+R) and type cmd", otherwise it's confusing with point 4.

Comment: On Windows 10 watch out for long paths when unzipping your node zip file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431338/folder-path-too-long-issue-in-installing-node-js-based-service/50561485#50561485

Comment: Still working on 20.9

Comment: Just a note about where to install it - make it a folder that isn't in OneDrive, the same goes for your projects since OneDrive will take forever saving the thousands of files that are generated inside of `node_modules`. To backup your projects use Git.

Comment: `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` is the key here. Accessing Environment Variables using any other method I know requires admin rights.

Comment: I put it in `%HOMEPATH%/AppData/Local/Programs/nodeJS/`. The above worked like a charm. Thank-you

Answer (score 25):

Just download the windows binary (NOT the msi installer) from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), unzip the file, then add the location of the `node.exe` file to system path. This means that after unzipping the downloaded binary, you get a folder, then you have to open that folder itself. That is the path you should add to system path.

To add to system path, do this, thanks to [Abdel Raoof](http://abdelraoof.com/blog/2014/11/11/install-nodejs-without-admin-rights)

Open Run with dialog (Win + R). Copy and paste this line in your command line

`rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`.

In **User variables for user_name** (the top window) path of your environment variables dialog add the path to your unzipped node download.
To check for successful installation

```
node -v

npm -v
```

Comment: Glad to here that there's a comfortable solution now. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work, when i add the path and press OK and close the window, when i reopened it, it wasn't there. I tried adding the path many time but faced the same problem, any solutions??

Comment: I think its quite possible to download and install node.js indows binaries now. I actually downloaded and installed one recently from here <https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.14.1/node-v10.14.1-x64.msi>

Comment: I had the command line open and it took me a while to realize I had to restart it to confirm installation / use node. :)

Comment: @AashishKumar Make sure you are editing the Path environmental variable under user variables. When you click edit a new window will pop up. There you will click new and add the path to your unzipped folder and click ok.  Then open a new cmd prompt and try the listed commands.

Answer (score 15):

1. Download the node.js zip file from official page. https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Unzip the file.
3. Goto **Edit Environment Variables For Your Account**.
4. Add new path **/node-v10.14.2-win-x64\node-v10.14.2-win-x64**
5. That's it... now you have installed both node.js and npm.
6. Use **node -v** and **npm -v** to check installation.

Comment: Not working for me :( Do we need to restart the system after this?

Answer (score 9):

Add following paths to the `PATH` environment variable, if you have downloaded the Node.js Windows Binary (.zip)

1. `<your os root>\node-v10.16.1-win-x64\`
2. `<your os root>\node-v10.16.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\bin\`

Then test following commands from the command prompt:

```
node -v

npm -v
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided is too old now. Portable download for Node (including NPM) is available as a zip download and it word just out of the box. you just need to add the folder to the path.

Answer (score 2):

For [node](https://nodejs.org) portable installation in windows batch file with below command can also be created in node root directory(where **node.exe** file resides) which updates **[PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/path)** environment variable on execution and also directly through command prompt from node root directory

```
PATH %~dp0;%PATH%;
```

~dp0 : fetches current directory path in windows

Hopes that Helps

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://medium.com/@github.gkarthiks/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-in-non-admin-access-windows-machines-102fd461b54c:

---

**Step 1:** Download the nodeJS.exe file from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ by clicking on All download options (example: https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.1/) and choose the right Windows architecture and download it.

**Step 2:** Choose a folder for nodeJS. For example, C:\ProgramData\Applications\nodejs and save the downloaded file under this folder.

**Step 3:** Add the nodeJS folder to the environment variable PATH by executing the below command in the cmd.exe, or using the User Interface.
set PATH=C:\ProgramData\Applications\nodejs;%PATH% **OBS! Remember to restart your computer after setting the environment variable. (Windows 10)**

**Step 4:** Now download the stable version of npm from the below link by replacing the version.
https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-{VERSION}.tgz
*For example for npm version 6.4.1,* https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-6.4.1.tgz

**Step 5:** Now unzip the downloaded npm file anywhere and cd into package folder.
**(I used convert.io to convert tgz to zip for unzipping in Windows 10 https://convertio.co/tgz-converter/)**

**Step 6:** Execute the following command in the cmd.exe

```
node bin/npm-cli.js install npm -gf
```

**Step 7:** Execute the following commands to verify the installation of nodeJS and npm.

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer from @Anothony O. didn't work for me. I got it working following [these](http://abdelraoof.com/blog/2014/11/11/install-nodejs-without-admin-rights) instructions and by adding the following to node\node_modules\npm\npmrc

```
strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: Did you have any error message in order to know why it didn't work for you? Thank you

Comment: The link only works without the trailing slash: http://abdelraoof.com/blog/2014/11/11/install-nodejs-without-admin-rights

Comment: An easier and potentially more reliable way to change npm settings like that would be running the command `npm set strict-ssl false`.

Comment: This helps solve the error message when SSL validation fails "npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY ... request to https://registry.npmjs.org/... failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, npm is now included with the binary (.zip) [node download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).  So installing node and npm without admin rights is straightforward, though you need to manually add the node directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

However, as of v8.11.4, the binary was including npm v5.6.1.  Running `npm install npm@latest -g` complained about not being able to delete `npm.cmd` and `npx.cmd`.  Moving those files out of the node directory fixes that, but then you can't simply run `npm` on the command line, because `npm.cmd` is no longer on the node path.

Trying @Anthony O's approach of downloading the latest npm .zip and installing from there didn't work either, as it was complaining about `rimraf` not being installed.  It seemed like maybe the npm install script was assuming `rimraf` was installed globally.

What finally worked was changing to the node directory and specifying the full path to `npm-cli.js` from there:

```
node node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install -g npm@latest
```

I see that the node v8.12.0 package that was just released now includes npm v6.4.1, so the above shouldn't be necessary for now.

Answer (score 0):

Download the node js zip file, extract it to a folder. Then create a windows batch file to set path to node js folder(as you may not be able to set path the usual way witout admin rights). Then run your node/npm/npx commands from the same command window. You even can open Visual Studio Code from there. If you need step by step checkout this video : https://youtu.be/BLnbtsDIW_E

Answer (score -1):

Try GitHub [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install):

```
curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash -s -- -y
```

Comment: The question was specifically for Windows OS. This *might* work if you have the Linux Subsystem for Windows 10 or possibly with cygwin, but no typical Windows box would be able to grok that...