# How do I run node.js without admin privileges windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, admin

At school/robotics the robotics teachers can not give me admin for obvoius reasons. This why I can not play around with node.js. Any ways I can do this would be greatly appriected. Have a nice day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install NodeJS LTS on Windows as a local user (without admin rights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029089/how-to-install-nodejs-lts-on-windows-as-a-local-user-without-admin-rights)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the node js zip file, extract it to a folder. Then create a windows batch file to set path to node js folder. Then run your commands from the same command window. You even can open Visual Studio Code from there. If you need step by step checkout this video : https://youtu.be/BLnbtsDIW_E