# Why ng commands works only with 'as admin' in Vs Code and Command prompt

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, cmd

I am running in a issue last two days. When I open Vs code and Cmd as admin then only able to run `ng` commands.

- Cmd and as admin: `ng -v`, `where ng` - Working
- Vs code terminal as admin: `ng build`, `ng serve` - Working
- Cmd without admin: `ng -v`, `where ng` - Not working
- Vs code terminal without admin: `ng build`, `ng serve` - Not working

Getting error

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To get admin credentials everytime I need to raise a ticket. Always I dont have admin credentials.

How can I fix this issue?

I have below configuration

```
Node.js: C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm:     C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm

Angular CLI: 9.1.9
Node: 12.15.0
```

Environment variable in `Path`

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users\Username\node_modules\.bin
```

Comment: How was nodejs/npm installed? Do you have the same problem with other npm packages? Maybee try installing nodejs/npm without admin rights https://stackoverflow.com/a/37029090/2721865

Comment: @kai - Don't know when it was installed. Now I have uninstalled node.js and installed it again. It's working :) Thank you for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling `node.js` (from `programs and features`) .

Comment: I had previously attempted with adjusting environment variables without success. But this does the trick.